# Rails MySQL Joins on null

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three tables.

`hospital_bed`, `patient` and `condition`.

each hospital bed can have one patient
each patient can have many conditions, but conditions can also be null in case it is not known yet

I basically want to display all beds and patients and then in a collapsable underneath all the conditions of the patient.

For that, I need to join these three tables like this:

```
HospitalBed.joins(:patient).joins('JOIN condition ON patient.id = condition.patient_id')
```

This way I receive all beds and patients and their conditions *except the patients that do not have a condition listed yet.*

How do I also get them? I know this would work

```
HospitalBed.joins(:patient).joins('JOIN conditions')
```

But this generates way too many rows than necessary.

Edit:
I want to get all beds and all patients **no matter if they have a condition or not**. All I can return are patients that have conditions but I also want the ones that *do not* have one (yet).

This but via the HospitalBed

```
Patient.left_joins(:conditions).merge(Condition.where.not(id: nil).or(Condition.where(id: nil)))
```

Comment: @dbugger returns the same as my first query

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
try association and let me know after that if you still face issue

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a SQL string here. You just need to setup your associations properly:

```
class HostipitalBed
  belongs_to :patient
  has_many :conditions, through: :patient
end
```

And then you need to figure out what you actually mean by "How do I also get them?":

```
HostipitalBed.joins(:conditions)        # Left inner join
HostipitalBed.left_joins(:conditions)   # Left outer join 
HostipitalBed.includes(:conditions)     # Loads the conditions in a separate query to avoid n+1
HostipitalBed.eager_load(:conditions)   # Loads the conditions in a single query to avoid n+1
```

Both `joins` and `left_joins` don't actually select anything from the joined table. If you want to display the conditions you want to use include/eager load to avoid a n+1 query issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails will do an INNER JOIN per default when using `joins` with a symbol. That means only relations will be returned that have matching records on both sides.

But when you want a JOIN to return also relations where one of the records does not exist, then you need to use an OUTER JOIN. Ruby on Rails has the `left_outer_joins` for those cases. But unfortunately you cannot use that method, because you will need the OUTER JOIN on a nested association.

Therefore, in your case the best option seems to be the writing the JOIN statement yourself, like this:

```
HospitalBed
  .joins(:patient)
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN conditions ON patients.id = conditions.patient_id')
```

Please note that when writing the join statement manually, then you need to use the real tables names in plural like they are named in the database.

Comment: Wot? You can easily create joins for nested assocations with `joins(foo: :bar)`.

Comment: @max Sure, but not with mixed symbol and string joins.

Comment: But do they really need a string join here?

Comment: I think so, because there is no `:conditions` association on `hospital_beds`.